# Inequality Check

Tags: inequality

Is this inequality correct?

> For all $x,y\in \mathbb R$,
>   $$\left|x+y^2\right| \geq \sqrt{x^2+y^2}.$$

[Source.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRn4B.jpg)

Is this inequality correct? If there is an error, please tell.

Comment: It is incorrect. Simply take $x = y = -1$ as a counterexample.

Comment: Whats the correct inequality for LHS as i have to use that in epsilon -delta approach in in continuity

Comment: It can be many different expressions, like $2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ or $\max\{\sqrt{x^2+y^2},1\}$. The important thing is for what kind of results you are looking for.

Comment: Let $x=-y^2<0$...

Answer (score 0):

Try $x=-5$ and $y=2$, you will see that this fails.

Comment: El Chapo, Whats the correct inequality for LHS as i have to use that in epsilon -delta approach in continuity,

Comment: Continuity of what?

Comment: ((x^2)+2y)/(x+(y^2)) at x=1, y=2 using epsilon delta approach